# Next number in the sequence || General approach

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, mathematica-8

how can I find the next number in this sequence ,

`1, 4, 7, 8, 13, 12, 9 , ?`

How to check , given any sequence of numbers , feasible or not. Any general theory or approach is very much welcomed .

Answer (score 0):

One method is to go to the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) and enter your list of at least six or eight numbers into the box and see if that happens to be a known sequence. For your example this doesn't find a known sequence.

If that doesn't work then you can try Mathematica's `FindFormula`

```
p=FindFormula[{1, 4, 7, 8, 13, 12, 9}];
```

and then

```
p[1] returns 1, p[2] returns 4, p[3] returns 7... and p[8] returns 106, etc.
```

You can read the documentation on `FindFormula` and you can look at the formula p by using `InputForm[p]` where `#1` represents a variable in the function p.

In general I think this is rarely going to produce the result that you are looking for.

Comment: But the Question paper in which I have seen this question saying the answer is 16. So how can I make sure that the question is error proof.

Answer (score 0):

```
seq = FindSequenceFunction[{1, 4, 7, 8, 13, 12, 9}, n]
```

> (48 - 74 n - 14 n^2 + 11 n^3 - n^4)/(3 (-13 + 3 n))

Checking the 7th number

```
n = 7;
seq
```

> 9

The next number is a fraction, apparently

```
n = 8;
seq
```

> 32/11

```
Show[Plot[seq, {n, 1, 10}],
 ListPlot[Table[seq, {n, 1, 10}]],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-20, 30}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]